# Implement repository service in java

Tags: java, web-services, repository, repository-pattern

I want to have a repository of Url to music(audio and video) with different file types (mp3,ogg,flv,avi) which can be used as a web-service.

Is there a free or open source solution for a repository (for example written in Java) which could help me, or do you have some recommendations, or patterns that could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely clear on what you are asking, but this sounds like a good use case for a [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) document store. If I were you, I'd be looking into things like [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/), [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) , etc.

CouchDB provides an HTTP interface via RESTful calls to your documents. So you could store your media in it, and you'd have a URL for each media element. There are [Java libraries](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Java) to support it, plus it's just REST with JSON, so it is really easy to get it working with Java. Personally, I use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for JSON processing.

I'm not sure about a pure Java solution, perhaps [JackRabbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Jackrabbit)? But it seems it may be overkill for your needs. It wouldn't be hard to roll your own. Perhaps use [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) to implement REST, and then just store files on the filesystem. I guess it all depends on the scale you need.

Hope this helps.